# Binding a value from a parent table into a DataGridView's text box using the foreign key

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` which list all users found in a database. Now, every user has its type. So, when it comes to low level, a user table has a foreign key column called user_type_id which points to `user_type` table (where it represents the primary key).

Also, I have implemented two-way binding, and I have combobox on a form on the same window, that updates the type of a user. The actual problem is with grid view and in its settings (`Edit Columns...` option) among others, the important values looks like this :

> Header Text - User Type
>
> DataPropertyName - user_type_id
>
> ColumnType - DataGridViewTextBoxColumn

So in my grid view, because I only have access to a foreign key colum (user_type_id), I only can show those ids, rather than a real name of a user type (which is stored in parent table - user_type).

How do you handle this ? Is there some setting that I am missing or I should fetch this manually rather than expecting for some automatic solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using a combobox column for the User_Type_ID column.  There you can fill the combo with names of the user types.  This is the easiest way I know to display meaningful values from a foreign key table but only store the ID value in the main table you are displaying/editing.

A simple example below:

```
var comboCol = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
comboCol.DataSource = GetUserTypeNames(); // Retrive these from your database somehow
comboCol.ValueMember = "user_type_id";
comboCol.DisplayMember = "user_type_name";
// This will display just the text
comboCol.DisplayStyle = DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.Nothing;
```

Comment: Yeah thanks, I had that in mind. So, you suggest that I fill the combobox, and then I guess, to make it disabled? Because I don't need it chageable?

Comment: Correct - I think `ReadOnly` is the way to go.  But aren't you providing a combo outside of the grid to update the user type?  Why not just do it within the grid and get rid of the combo you have now?

Comment: Well, because I use grid only to show the list and have a form for updating / deleting / adding users. That is a request.And IMO, it is a bit more user friendly than having all of the mentioned things done by grid view (even if a grid view can do all that) ..

Comment: @jaredbaszier Actually, your solution just needed one little modification... There is a DisplayStyle property for a bound column, with three options: Combobox, DropDownButton and Nothing. I have chosen Nothing, and now it looks like it is just text... :)

Comment: Nice find - I was unaware of that.  I've updated the answer.