# DataGridView Column Will Not Show Values That Were Set. They show up blank in the GUI

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, datagridview, entity-framework-6

My end goal is to replace the Foreign Key Id for the pulled table to get a persons name instead. Any help with that would be great. I am using EF6 context DbSet as the binding source for the DataGridView.

It pulls the whole table though which isn't clean enough for the GUI. So I remove Id column and others eventually. Then I add a new column called named Person Name.

Literally everything is working perfectly how I need it. It's just not displaying the values of the persons names in the DGV cells.

```
using (var ctx = new myDbContext())
{ 
    BindingSource bSrc = new BindingSource();
    bSrc.DataSource = ctx.myDbSet.ToList();
    myDataGridView.DataSource = bSrc;
    myDataGridView.Refresh();
}
myDataGridView.Columns.Add("originalPerson", "Person Name");

myDataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

myDataGridView.Columns.Remove("Id");
myDataGridView.Columns.Remove("DateModified");
myDataGridView.Columns.Remove("DateCreated");

using (var ctx = new myDbContext())
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow r in myDataGridView.Rows)
    {

        int pId= (Int32)r.Cells[0].Value;
        string name = ctx.personsTable.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == pId).name;
//Where I set the values.
        r.Cells[myDataGridView.Columns.Count - 1].Value = name.ToUpper();
    }
}

myDataGridView.Columns.Remove("personsTableId");

if (myDataGridView!= null)
{
    myDataGridView.Columns[myDataGridView.ColumnCount - 1].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
}
```

If anyone thinks I should do it another way I am all ears I feel like this got messy fast. Thanks in advance! I went ahead and showed everything I had.

Comment: can  you locate the issue by stepping through the code setting breakpoints..?

Comment: When I stepped through the program it sets up the value just fine and puts the name in the right cell. The GUI just shows up my farthest to the right/new column like there was nothing there. I feel like it has something to do with me adding values into the DGV without going through some redrawing or refreshing but, update/refresh don't work.

Comment: what event are you doing all the code in that you posted..?

Comment: Form Load basically right after the Visual Studio IntializeComponents generated method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered a similar question yesterday and I would suggest the same solution for you:

[Binding a value from a parent table into a DataGridView's text box using the foreign key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45469864/binding-a-value-from-a-parent-table-into-a-datagridviews-text-box-using-the-for/45471107#45471107)

Also - instead of removing the column's you don't want, I would suggest hiding them `Visible = false`.  That way you can reference those values/columns later on if you need them.